# Creating substrings array from a string

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a string that has no spaces and I wanted to create an array that consists of the substrings of the word. For instance, let the string is **stackoverflow** The array should be like:

> [sta, cko, ver, flo, w]

The code that I use is below and that does give me only the first item. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getWords(String s){
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i=i+3){
        words.add(s.substring(i, 3));
    }
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, the "3" in

```
s.substring(i, 3)
```

means the 3rd index from the beginning of the string, not the 3rd index from i, so you'd want

```
s.substring(i, i + 3)
```

Second, if the string is shorter than i + 3, you'll get an exception. To solve this, you can use Math.min. It would look something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getWords(String s){
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i=i+3){
    words.add(s.substring(i, Math.min(i + 3, i.length())));
}
return words;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `i + 3` as the second parameter of the `substring` call (it takes begin and end indexes). Also, I would prefer to program to the `List` interface. You might use `+=` instead of `i = i + 3`. And you need an `else` clause for when there aren't three letters in the `String`. Like,

```
public static List<String> getWords(String s) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 3) {
        if (i + 3 < s.length()) {
            words.add(s.substring(i, i + 3));
        } else {
            words.add(s.substring(i));
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Then, for completeness, I tested it with a basic `main` method like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getWords("stackoverflow"));
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
[sta, cko, ver, flo, w]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but your `substring` should be `(i, i+3)` as the following:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getWords(String s){
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i+=3){
        if (i+3 >= s.length())
            words.add(s.substring(i));
        else
            words.add(s.substring(i, i+3));
    }
    return words;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ease it significantly by using guava's [Splitter](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter):

```
String f = "stackoverflow";
List<String> p = Splitter.fixedLength(3).splitToList(f);
System.out.println(p); // [sta, cko, ver, flo, w]
```